# Dense open subset of R with uncountable complement

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with uncountable complement?

I began by considering $\mathbb{Q}$ as a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the irrationals as its uncountable complement. However, this example does not work as $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed. Is it possible to modify this example to satisfy the criteria that the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be both dense and open? Or is there perhaps a better example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example. Define $C$ as the Cantor set, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set, which is closed, nowhere dense and uncountable. Then $A:=\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is your open and dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which you are looking for.

Comment: "Very simple example"

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your idea using $\mathbb{Q}$ as follows.

Let $(r_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then define $A_n = (r_n - 2^{-n},r_n+2^{-n})$ and set $\tilde{Q} = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$.

Now, since $A_n$ are open $\tilde{Q}$ is open as a union of open sets.

Further, $\tilde{Q}$ is dense since $\mathbb{Q}\subset \tilde{Q} $. And the complement of $\tilde{Q}$ is uncountable since $\tilde{Q}$ has finite measure. Indeed, using subadditivity we find $|\tilde{Q}| \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} 2\cdot \frac{1}{2^n} =2$.

Comment: @Juanito thanks, fixed!

Comment: It is a nice idea  :)